# How can I perform version control of Procedures, Views, and Functions in Postgres sql

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to do a versioning control of my database.

I currently control my front-end applications through git, however I am creating my database and would like to have a versioning of my tables, function and procedures, how can I accomplish this for database?
That is, I will make a change in a function but I would like to save the previous one I was executing in case there is any problem I can put the previous one again.

Comment: Put the SQL scripts into Git or Subversion, just like any other source code. Use something like Liquibase or Flyway to run the migrations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Major tools for versioning of database structure including optional data migration are:

- [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)
- [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)

However, the specifics of your question are beyond what existing tools offer today.

If you need to have two or more versions of some object in the database for parallel use (e.g. step-by-step migration of tables, triggers, aso.) you are better off using either:

1. a naming scheme embedded into the objects, e.g. `my_cool_function_v2` vs. `my_cool_function_v3`

...or:

2. use a different database schema for every major version (if you adhere to the semantic version approach), e.g. `CREATE FUNCTION my_schema_v2.my_cool_function` will not collide with `my_schema_v1.my_cool_function`

In both cases, you usually have to manage referencing the newer version where wanted. For the second approach, this can be further simplified with the schema [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH), which you can modify to prefer a new schema containing new versions of the objects, e.g. with:

```sql
SET search_path TO my_schema_v2, my_schema_v1, public;
```

dynamically (useful for testing in the live system without affecting actual applications/users) and once you are confident the basics are set, include it into the PostgreSQL configuration (`postgresql.conf`) so that the new schema becomes standard for every new connection:

```
search_path = 'my_schema_v2, my_schema_v1, public'
```

After you have migrated all of the new objects and everything is working fine, you can remove the old `my_schema_v1` from the `search_path` and also `DROP ... CASCADE` it to remove all the old objects at once.

However, one downside of the schema approach is that if you always create all objects (functions, triggers, tables, ...) in all schemas, you'll lose the benefits of it when combined with the `search_path`. Therefore, I would create different schemas for different objects, e.g. `data_v1` for the data (tables, indexes, ...) and `func_v1` for other things (functions, procedures, ...). That way you can evolve the structure independently of the data but at the same time, you can also start evolving the table structure and automatically benefit from fixes/improvements in functions but also test whether changes are forward-compatible.

Comment: The only downside I see in this approach is that if you have all your data in the `data_vX` schema, and your functions in the `func_vY` schema, then you can't organize your various data tables into schemas, as PostgreSQL doesn't support nested schemas (as of Version 13, at least).

Answer (score 4):

Hi future readers of this Q, I am the maintainer of project [#yuniql](https://github.com/rdagumampan/yuniql): a schema versioning and migration tool than you can run with zero dependencies. In scenario described, most tools treats every change in the database as immutable or atomic change and if you need to rollback your change, it will just be another minor or major version. This way you can fully reconstruct the database anywhere, anytime and at the same time tracks the evolution of your database schema.

In yuniql, your workspace will typically be organized like this

```
v0.00
 + create_schema.sql
 + create_table_customers.sql
v0.01
 + create_table_custmomers_with_contact.sql
v0.02
 + create_table_custmomers_with_picture.sql
```

You may refer to github for getting started and samples ;)
https://github.com/rdagumampan/yuniql
https://yuniql.io/docs/get-started-postgresql/

Br, Rodel